# how to avoid login without verified email asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

At the moment in my code when I write:

```
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
```

The user is signed in, even without verified email.
Where do I need to configure the Signin manager to deny sign-in with unverified email?
Or do I have to look into the db the information about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've been using for this is to prevent the SignInAsync during login POST and yes, that would use the db information.

In your login POST method, just add a boolean check for the Email Verified property before doing a SignInAsync. You don't have to copy the code below completely, just add the boolean check.

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult YourLoginMethod(loginModel model){
      // get user
      var user = db.ApplicationUsers.Where(a=>a.Key == model.Key).FirstOrDefault();

      if(user!=null){
         if(user.IsEmailVerified){
            // if the email verified property is true call SignInAsync
            var result = await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
            // .. code redirect here
         }else{
            // tell the user that his email is not verified return to a view with error
            return View();
         }
      }

      // cant find user
      return View();
   }
```

---

Or if you want to modify SignInManager, you could actually inherit from it and override SignInAsync because SignInAsync is virtual as mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.signinasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_SignInManager_1_SignInAsync__0_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_AuthenticationProperties_System_String_).

```
   public class CustomSignInManager:SignInManager{
      public override Task SignInAsync(...){
         // check for user email verified first with db context

         if(emailIsVerified){
            // call base class implementation
            base.SignInAsync(...)
         }
      }
   }
```